# Java Scope dilemma

Tags: java

As per Java's scoping rule, objects declared in the outer scope will be visible to code within the inner scope and not vice versa.

Now, consider this program:

```
    public class Scope {
    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int x = 10; //known to all code within main

        if (x == 10) {
            int y = 20;
            System.out.println("x and y: " + x  + " " + y);
            x = y * 2;
        }

        //y = 100;
        System.out.println("x is: " + x);
    }
}
```

Its output is:

`x and y: 10 20`
`x is: 40`

Why is `x` `40` here? `x = y * 2` was inside `if`, therefore, `y` is localized there so shouldn't `x` be `20` again the second time? How come the `x` fetched the `40` from within `if` since the objects declared within inner scope are not visible outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is declared outside of the `if` statement so it's scope is **whole** `main` method (no matter if it's changed inside any loops inside that `main` method, all changes affect it as it's declared outside). `y` is declared inside of `if` statement so you can't use it outside it, but all changes made to `x` inside the `if` are visible to `x` outside, as it's declared outside.

Answer (score 1):

`y` is limited in scope there it is true, but `x` is not. And `20 * 2` is `40`. `x = 40` is the assignment, and `x` is still visible after the block. The `x` didn't "fetch" forty, forty was assigned to `x` (and then `y` goes out of scope). You can think of it like,

```
if (x == 10) {
    System.out.println("x and y: " + x + " 20");
    x = 40;
}
```

Notice `y` can be removed entirely from the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Scope {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // visible to whole main()
        int x = 10; //known to all code within main

        if (x == 10) {
            // visible to if statement only
            int y = 20;
            System.out.println("x and y: " + x + " " + y);
            // this is not local x, this is int x = 10 from main function
            x = y * 2;
        }

        // y is not visible here (this is not if block)
        // x is visible and modified
        System.out.println("x is: " + x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A new function defines a new, limited Scope:

```
public class Scope {

public class Scope {
   static void newScope (int x) {
        // y visible to method only
        int y = 20;
        System.out.println("x and y: " + x + " " + y);
        // this is the local x, it came from the the main function
        // but is a local copy
        x = y * 2;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // visible to whole main()
        int x = 10; //known to all code within main

        if (x == 10) {
            newScope (x);
        }

        // y is not visible here (this is alien to the newScope Method)
        // x is visible but unmodified
        System.out.println("x is: " + x);
    }
}
```